# My php script is not sending an email when called by a cron job

Tags: php, cron

I am running a cron job every five minutes which calls a php script to check to see if users have imported any files for processing.

When I run the php script by going to the address in my web browser it runs the script and then sends the user a notification by email. When I run the script using the cron job, the script works fine, but it doesn't send the user an email. Any thoughts about why no email is sent?

I'm running Ubuntu Hardy LTS. The cron job is:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -–delete-after http://www.mywebsite.com/import_processing.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I'm using delete-after so that I don't get copies of the script piling up in my server directory. I'm suppressing output and errors also as I don't need email confirmation myself.

The script uses the basic mail function, and as I said, works just fine when run from my browser.

Update: It looks like the issue is my php script is looking for a browser cookie to send the email. I imagine I'll have to find another way to get the user's identity.

Comment: Try piping the output to a file just once to see if there is an error or otherwise unexpected occurrence.

Comment: There's no output from the file. I did let it email me and there was nothing unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run it like this

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/htdocs/blah/blah/import_processing.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

when you use wget you are downloading the file,
with php you are running the file,
test your script running

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/htdocs/blah/blah/import_processing.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

using the local path, just in case run

```
$ which php
```

to figure out where it is installed

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I got the same result. I think I have an idea of the problem. The script relies on reading a browser cookie to find the email address of the user, which I imagine won't work using wget or running php. So unless I'm wrong, I'll have to rewrite it to get around the browser cookie issue.

Comment: Yes I suggest you do that. And use php, this way you can generate the output using echo or var_dump and without any of the pipes like >/dev/null 2>&1 so you can see what is going.  It seems like a better approach to use php for a local php file than wget.

Answer (score 0):

The script was running properly using wget or php; the problem was that the php script looked for a browser cookie which didn't exist when the page was run outside of a web browser.

I changed the php script to do a database lookup instead and it worked just fine. Thanks for your suggestions.